# AndroidWifiModule.java uses o r overrides a deprecated API

Tags: java, android, android-studio, react-native

I downloaded react-native-android-wifi modules but when I run the code it says `AndroidWifiModule.java` uses o r overrides a deprecated API. Also its cannot connect to a network in android 8, so I added this line

```
//conf.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            conf.SSID = ssid;
        } else {
            conf.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";
        }
```

is that true?
Here is the code :

```
public class AndroidWifiModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

//WifiManager Instance
WifiManager wifi;
ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

//Constructor
public AndroidWifiModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);

    wifi = (WifiManager)reactContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
}

//Name for module register to use:
@Override
public String getName() {
    return "AndroidWifiModule";
}

//Method to load wifi list into string via Callback. Returns a stringified JSONArray
@ReactMethod
public void loadWifiList(Callback successCallback, Callback errorCallback) {
    try {
        List < ScanResult > results = wifi.getScanResults();
        JSONArray wifiArray = new JSONArray();

            for (ScanResult result: results) {
                JSONObject wifiObject = new JSONObject();
                if(!result.SSID.equals("")){
                    try {
                        wifiObject.put("SSID", result.SSID);
                        wifiObject.put("BSSID", result.BSSID);
                        wifiObject.put("capabilities", result.capabilities);
                        wifiObject.put("frequency", result.frequency);
                        wifiObject.put("level", result.level);
                        wifiObject.put("timestamp", result.timestamp);
                        //Other fields not added
                        //wifiObject.put("operatorFriendlyName", result.operatorFriendlyName);
                        //wifiObject.put("venueName", result.venueName);
                        //wifiObject.put("centerFreq0", result.centerFreq0);
                        //wifiObject.put("centerFreq1", result.centerFreq1);
                        //wifiObject.put("channelWidth", result.channelWidth);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        errorCallback.invoke(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    wifiArray.put(wifiObject);
                }
            }
            successCallback.invoke(wifiArray.toString());
        } catch (IllegalViewOperationException e) {
            errorCallback.invoke(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    //Method to force wifi usage if the user needs to send requests via wifi
    //if it does not have internet connection. Useful for IoT applications, when
    //the app needs to communicate and send requests to a device that have no 
    //internet connection via wifi.

    //Receives a boolean to enable forceWifiUsage if true, and disable if false.
    //Is important to enable only when communicating with the device via wifi 
    //and remember to disable it when disconnecting from device.
    @ReactMethod
    public void forceWifiUsage(boolean useWifi) {
        boolean canWriteFlag = false;

        if (useWifi) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    canWriteFlag = Settings.System.canWrite(reactContext);

                    if (!canWriteFlag) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + reactContext.getPackageName()));
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        reactContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

                if (((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) && canWriteFlag) || ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) && !(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M))) {
                    final ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) reactContext
                            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkRequest.Builder builder;
                    builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
                    //set the transport type do WIFI
                    builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);


                    manager.requestNetwork(builder.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                manager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
                            } else {
                                //This method was deprecated in API level 23
                                ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(network);
                            }
                            try {
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            manager.unregisterNetworkCallback(this);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) reactContext
                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                manager.bindProcessToNetwork(null);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(null);
            }
        }
    }

    //Method to check if wifi is enabled
    @ReactMethod
    public void isEnabled(Callback isEnabled) {
        isEnabled.invoke(wifi.isWifiEnabled());
    }

    //Method to connect/disconnect wifi service
    @ReactMethod
    public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(enabled);
    }

    //Send the ssid and password of a Wifi network into this to connect to the network.
    //Example:  wifi.findAndConnect(ssid, password);
    //After 10 seconds, a post telling you whether you are connected will pop up.
    //Callback returns true if ssid is in the range
    @ReactMethod
    public void findAndConnect(String ssid, String password, Callback ssidFound) {
        List < ScanResult > results = wifi.getScanResults();
        boolean connected = false;
        for (ScanResult result: results) {
            String resultString = "" + result.SSID;
            if (ssid.equals(resultString)) {
                connected = connectTo(result, password, ssid);
            }
        }
        ssidFound.invoke(connected);
    }

    //Use this method to check if the device is currently connected to Wifi.
    @ReactMethod
    public void connectionStatus(Callback connectionStatusResult) {
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getReactApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
            connectionStatusResult.invoke(true);
        } else {
            connectionStatusResult.invoke(false);
        }
    }

    //Method to connect to WIFI Network
    public Boolean connectTo(ScanResult result, String password, String ssid) {
        //Make new configuration
        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();

        //clear alloweds
        conf.allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear();
        conf.allowedGroupCiphers.clear();
        conf.allowedKeyManagement.clear();
        conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.clear();
        conf.allowedProtocols.clear();

        // Quote ssid and password
        //conf.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            conf.SSID = ssid;
        } else {
            conf.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";
        }

        WifiConfiguration tempConfig = this.IsExist(conf.SSID);
        if (tempConfig != null) {
            wifi.removeNetwork(tempConfig.networkId);
        }

        String capabilities = result.capabilities;

        // appropriate ciper is need to set according to security type used
        if (capabilities.contains("WPA") || capabilities.contains("WPA2") || capabilities.contains("WPA/WPA2 PSK")) {

            // This is needed for WPA/WPA2 
            // Reference - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.java#149
            conf.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);

            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);

            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);

            conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
            conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);

            conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
            conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
            conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
            conf.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", password);

        } else if (capabilities.contains("WEP")) {
            // This is needed for WEP
            // Reference - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.java#149
            conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + password + "\"";
            conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
            conf.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
            conf.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
        } else {
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        }

        List<WifiConfiguration> mWifiConfigList = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
        int updateNetwork = -1;

        // Use the existing network config if exists
        for (WifiConfiguration wifiConfig : mWifiConfigList) {
            if (wifiConfig.SSID.equals(conf.SSID)) {
                conf=wifiConfig;
                updateNetwork=conf.networkId;
            }
        }

        // If network not already in configured networks add new network
        if ( updateNetwork == -1 ) {
          updateNetwork = wifi.addNetwork(conf);
          wifi.saveConfiguration();
        }

        // if network not added return false
        if ( updateNetwork == -1 ) {
            return false;
        }

        // disconnect current network
        boolean disconnect = wifi.disconnect();
        if ( !disconnect ) {
            return false;
        }

        // enable new network
        boolean enableNetwork = wifi.enableNetwork(updateNetwork, true);
        if ( !enableNetwork ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    //add configuration of hidden network and return it's networkId
    public int setWifiConfig(String ssid, String sharedKey) {
        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();

        conf.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";
        conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + sharedKey + "\"";

        conf.hiddenSSID = true;
        conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
        conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);

        return wifi.addNetwork(conf);
    }

    //Add a hidden wifi network and connect to it
    //Example:  wifi.connectToHiddenNetwork(ssid, password, (networkAdded) => {});
    //Callback returns true if network added and tried to connect to it successfully
    //It may take up to 15s to connect to hidden networks
    @ReactMethod
    public void connectToHiddenNetwork(String ssid, String password, Callback networkAdded) {
        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
        int updateNetwork = -1;

        // check if network config exists and it's hidden
        for (WifiConfiguration wifiConfig : list) {
            if (wifiConfig.SSID.equals("\"" + ssid + "\"") && wifiConfig.hiddenSSID) {
                updateNetwork = wifiConfig.networkId;
            }
        }

        // If network not already in configured networks add new network
        if (updateNetwork == -1) {
            updateNetwork = setWifiConfig(ssid, password);
        }

        // if network not added return false
        if (updateNetwork == -1) {
            networkAdded.invoke(false);
            return;
        }

        // disconnect current network
        boolean disconnect = wifi.disconnect();
        if (!disconnect) {
            networkAdded.invoke(false);
            return;
        }

        // enable new network
        boolean enableNetwork = wifi.enableNetwork(updateNetwork, true);
        if (!enableNetwork) {
            networkAdded.invoke(false);
            return;
        }

        // reconnect to new network
        boolean reconnect = wifi.reconnect();
        if (!reconnect) {
            networkAdded.invoke(false);
            return;
        }

        wifi.saveConfiguration();

        networkAdded.invoke(true);
    }

    //Disconnect current Wifi.
    @ReactMethod
    public void disconnect() {
        wifi.disconnect();
    }

    //This method will return current ssid
    @ReactMethod
    public void getSSID(final Callback callback) {
        WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();

        // This value should be wrapped in double quotes, so we need to unwrap it.
        String ssid = info.getSSID();
        if (ssid.startsWith("\"") && ssid.endsWith("\"")) {
            ssid = ssid.substring(1, ssid.length() - 1);
        }

        callback.invoke(ssid);
    }

    //This method will return the basic service set identifier (BSSID) of the current access point
    @ReactMethod
    public void getBSSID(final Callback callback) {
        WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();

        String bssid = info.getBSSID();

        callback.invoke(bssid.toUpperCase());
    }

    //This method will return current wifi signal strength
    @ReactMethod
    public void getCurrentSignalStrength(final Callback callback) {
        int linkSpeed = wifi.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
        callback.invoke(linkSpeed);
    }

    //This method will return current wifi frequency
    @ReactMethod
    public void getFrequency(final Callback callback) {
        WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
        int frequency = info.getFrequency();
        callback.invoke(frequency);
    }

    //This method will return current IP
    @ReactMethod
    public void getIP(final Callback callback) {
        WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
        String stringip = longToIP(info.getIpAddress());
        callback.invoke(stringip);
    }

    //This method will remove the wifi network as per the passed SSID from the device list
    @ReactMethod
    public void isRemoveWifiNetwork(String ssid, final Callback callback) {
        List<WifiConfiguration> mWifiConfigList = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for (WifiConfiguration wifiConfig : mWifiConfigList) {
            String comparableSSID = ('"' + ssid + '"'); //Add quotes because wifiConfig.SSID has them
            if(wifiConfig.SSID.equals(comparableSSID)) {
                wifi.removeNetwork(wifiConfig.networkId);
                wifi.saveConfiguration();
                callback.invoke(true);
                return;
            }
        }
        callback.invoke(false);
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void reScanAndLoadWifiList(Callback successCallback, Callback errorCallback) {
        WifiReceiver receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver(wifi, successCallback, errorCallback);
        getCurrentActivity().registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        wifi.startScan();
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void getDhcpServerAddress(Callback callback) {
        DhcpInfo dhcpInfo = wifi.getDhcpInfo();
        String ip = longToIP(dhcpInfo.serverAddress);
        callback.invoke(ip);
    }

    public static String longToIP(int longIp){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String[] strip=new String[4];
        strip[3]=String.valueOf((longIp >>> 24));
        strip[2]=String.valueOf((longIp & 0x00FFFFFF) >>> 16);
        strip[1]=String.valueOf((longIp & 0x0000FFFF) >>> 8);
        strip[0]=String.valueOf((longIp & 0x000000FF));
        sb.append(strip[0]);
        sb.append(".");
        sb.append(strip[1]);
        sb.append(".");
        sb.append(strip[2]);
        sb.append(".");
        sb.append(strip[3]);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private WifiConfiguration IsExist(String SSID) {
        List<WifiConfiguration> existingConfigs = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for (WifiConfiguration existingConfig : existingConfigs) {
            if (existingConfig.SSID.equals("\"" + SSID + "\"")) {
                return existingConfig;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private Callback successCallback;
        private Callback errorCallback;
        private WifiManager wifi;

        public WifiReceiver(final WifiManager wifi, Callback successCallback, Callback errorCallback) {
            super();
            this.successCallback = successCallback;
            this.errorCallback = errorCallback;
            this.wifi = wifi;
        }

        // This method call when number of wifi connections changed
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

            c.unregisterReceiver(this);

            try {
                List < ScanResult > results = this.wifi.getScanResults();
                JSONArray wifiArray = new JSONArray();

                for (ScanResult result: results) {
                    JSONObject wifiObject = new JSONObject();
                    if(!result.SSID.equals("")){
                        try {
                            wifiObject.put("SSID", result.SSID);
                            wifiObject.put("BSSID", result.BSSID);
                            wifiObject.put("capabilities", result.capabilities);
                            wifiObject.put("frequency", result.frequency);
                            wifiObject.put("level", result.level);
                            wifiObject.put("timestamp", result.timestamp);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            this.errorCallback.invoke(e.getMessage());
                            return;
                        }
                        wifiArray.put(wifiObject);
                    }
                }
                this.successCallback.invoke(wifiArray.toString());
                return;
            } catch (IllegalViewOperationException e) {
                this.errorCallback.invoke(e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and show the exact stacktrace as text. Show your research. _Why_ did you make those changes you refer to? Also, fixup the formatting of this question.

Comment: I want to connect to network programmatically but it fails on android 8

Comment: Details like this _should be in the question_. [Edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, what you tried, and what results you got.